# Can i pass some information in the same time from dbA to dbB?

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc

I have project Administration an project Employees. The project Administration use database dbAdministration and the project Employees use dbEmployees and i want to insert tax code in dbEmployees from the project Employees and in the same time insert it in dbAdministration to a table called "Conti" :
.

This is the insert method in `EmployeeDAO` (Dipendente DAO in italian) :

```
public boolean insertDipendente(String codicefiscale,String Nome,String 
Cognome,Timestamp Datadinascita,String Luogodinascita ) {

    boolean result = false;
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;

    String insertTableSQL = "INSERT INTO dipendenti" + "(Codicefiscale,Nome,Cognome,Datadinascita,Luogodinascita) VALUES" + "(?,?,?,?,?)";

    try {
        preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(insertTableSQL);
        preparedStatement.setString(1,codicefiscale);
        preparedStatement.setString(2, Nome); 
        preparedStatement.setString(3, Cognome);
        preparedStatement.setTimestamp(4, Datadinascita);
        preparedStatement.setString(5, Luogodinascita);

        // execute insert SQL stetement
        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
        result = true;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

How can I pass the tax code entered by the employee's insert to table `Conti` in `Administration` database?

In the `Administration` project I have a dbAdministration with `Conti' table that I manage through`CONTODAO`and`ContoEJB`.

In the `Employees` project I have a dbEMployees with `dipendenti' table that I manage through`DipendenteDAO`and`DipendenteEJB`.

Comment: specify "in the same time", note that at the same instant is generally not possible. Are you concerned about errors you will likely have to take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-phase_commit_protocol . Note that generally your classes, tables, variables should have english names.

Comment: create 2 connections to connect to both databases and either use a separate thread which should result in more "in the same time" or just execute them one after another. yet you would have to worry about transactions since 1 insert can fail and the other can pass

Comment: @Andrea Caponnetto i tried to answer your last answer but you delete !

Comment: @YCF_L yes because in this question the explanation is better!

Comment: can you help me @YCF_L?